# Need Help with Approval Process: When a user would like to mass/delete or transfer records they must be approved by the Office Manager

Tags: apex, workflow, process-builder, approval-process

I have never worked with approval processes so I would really appreciate your inputs.

An approval process needs to be be created based on ownership of accounts for mass record deletion and transfer. That is nobody shall be allowed to mass transfer or delete records without the approval of the Sales Coordinator or Office Manager.

Does anybody know the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: To get familiar with approval processes, I would strongly recommend you do: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/business_process_automation/units/approvals

Comment: This can't be done by an approval process. Typically handled by permissions on the profile. Users would not have permissions to do so. They would put in a request to the office manager who would then do it

Comment: @Eric Is there a way a user can submit request to the manager to delete or transfer records and then have the the user given the ability to delete/transfer records?

Comment: There is always a way but it would be extremely complex and fraught with potential issues. Salesforce runs on permissions and record security. If the user has permissions to delete and transfer ownership then they can delete the records they have access to. This is typical handled as a business process and the office manager would need to do it. Maybe someone here will have a great solution but IMHO this is a process change/improvement issue...